# remove az cli default (how do I?)

Tags: azure-cli

I've configured my az cli to default my resource group, how do I remove/undo that?

```
az configure --default group=blah
```

```
PS C:\Users\blah> az configure -l
[
  {
    "name": "group",
    "source": "C:\\Users\\blah\\.azure\\config",
    "value": "blah"
  }
]
```

reference: [CLI configuration with az config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-configuration#cli-configuration-with-az-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re-run the command to set the default w/ no value:

```
az configure --default group=
```

```
PS C:\Users\mdepouw> az configure -l
[]
```